# AWS Kibana/ElasticSearch - attempting to retrieve Alerting Monitors using Dev Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

I'm trying to use Dev Tools in Kibana 7.10.2 with Open Distro for Elasticsearch to access my monitors. I want to see the 'raw' values as per [this Opensearch link](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/observing-your-data/alerting/api/#get-monitor) but when I run the following query in Dev Tools I get:

```
GET _plugins/_alerting/monitors/GFUJ74UBxx7lnTALELU3

{
  "error" : "no handler found for uri [/_plugins/_alerting/monitors/GFUJ74UBxx7lnTALELU3?pretty=true] and method [GET]"
}
```

I'm not sure of the monitor id but I got it from the URL on the monitor page, and there's no documentation that I've found, that explains where to get the id from. I also cannot list all existing monitors or [search by name](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/observing-your-data/alerting/api/#search-monitors) in order to retrieve the monitor id that way:

```
GET _plugins/_alerting/monitors/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match" : {
      "monitor.name": "[REDACTED]"
    }
  }
}

{
  "error" : "no handler found for uri [/_plugins/_alerting/monitors/_search?pretty=true] and method [GET]"
}
```

And I've checked the ['correct' documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.17/create-and-manage-rules.html), which more closely matches the Elasticsearch version I'm operating, but the docs and screenshots don't even match anything I have in the Alerting section. The [OpenDistro](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/) page points us towards Opensearch...

How do I use Dev Tools to retrieve a monitor? And why isn't the API working as per the docs?!

Comment: As an aside, the reason I need to retrieve the monitor via dev tools is to debug terraform (https://github.com/phillbaker/terraform-provider-elasticsearch/tree/master) setting monitor interval unit to 'minutes' in the UI despite terraform plan showing no changes when commanding unit to 'hours'...